# Remove selected text from uitextview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have a textview and i need to be able to remove the selected text [ i mean i want to delete the text which are highlighted] for that i did as below

Code

```
(void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSRange range = textView.selectedRange;
   myTextView.text = [myTextView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];

}
```

but it is crashing , how to implement this functionality here

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: Range or index out of bounds'
```

Pls let me know

Comment: check the -ve sign is not present in your code. It should be like this -(void) textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView

Comment: It is not clear.. While highlighting itself, it will give options to copy, cut, etc., Can you please explain why you need this programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working fine on xcode version 3.2.5. Check the delegates of the UITextView are connected to the file Owner in the Interface Builder.

```
-(void) textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {     
NSRange range = textView.selectedRange;
myTextView.text = [myTextView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
}
```

Comment: What if I want to undo this action? What's the right way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This code is  working in my simulator, please check delegates  connection(from UITextView to File owner)and (File owner to  UITextView) in Interfacebuilder